# What does this error message for struct mean?

Tags: c, struct, registration

I tried to make a small registration programm dividing it in a header, a source code containing the registration function definition and the main code.

However, i get this error message:
`error: expected expression before 'struct'.`

What did I do wrong? Please help I'm a beginner. Here's my main code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "registration.h"

int main()
{
   int choice;
   puts("Press 1 to register");
   scanf("%d", &choice);

   if(choice==1){
       registerUser(struct generalUser user);
}
}
```

This my header code.

```
struct generalUser{
    char fName[15];
    char lName[20];
    int id;
    int bDay;
    int bMonth;
    int bYear;
};

struct generalUser user;

void registerUser(struct generalUser user);
```

Here's my code for defining the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void registerUser(struct generalUser user){
    srand(time(NULL));

    puts("Insert name");
    scanf("%s", user.fName);

    puts("Insert last name");
    scanf("%s", user.lName);

    user.id=1 + rand()%9999;
    printf("You ID code is %d", &user.id);

    printf("Insert date of birth in the following format: dd/mm/yy");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &user.bDay, &user.bMonth, &user.bYear);


    printf("%s %s, id %d, %d/%d/%d", user.fName, user.lName, user.id, user.bDay, user.bMonth, user.bYear);
}
```

Comment: There is no `#include "registration.h"` in your last code snippet. Is that a transcription error, or is it in your actual code? If the latter, then that's the problem.

Comment: Look at how you're calling `printf`, `scanf`, and `puts`, then look at your you're calling `registerUser`.  Notice a difference?

Comment: @Adrian Mole i fixed that but now it says undefined reference to "registerUser". I even changed registerUser(struct generalUser user) to simply registerUser(user) but the new error remains.

Comment: You probably only want to call `srand` *once* in your program. Never do `scanf("%s", ...);`, at least give a length option to `%s`. What is the purpose of passing the `user` parameter to `registerUser`?

Comment: Oh, and don't use global variables when learning C. Globals have their uses, but they tend to make beginners skip learning about proper use of parameters.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code between your code editor and the question, don't type things manually. Not only is it a waste of time, but also leads to errors. Surround code blocks with `\`\`\`` on separate lines - that way you don't need to mess with indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs in your source:

1. `printf("You ID code is %d", &user.id);` : please remove & because what your are printing is its value not ref
2. In main `registerUser(struct generalUser user);`, please remove `struct generalUser`. You are calling a function having user already declared global.

Comment: But, even passing `user` as an argument won't work. That's passing a **copy** of the global variable. The function will make changes to that copy, and leave the 'original' intact. Or, it might work in this case, as the OP's code doesn't do anything with the global `user` after calling the function ... but, you know ...

Comment: @Tiny Sonhh i applied these fixes but a new error came up: undefined reference to registerUser

Comment: @Tiziano666 how do you compile and link your code files?

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm using CodeBlocks and this is my first try with a project divided in several files (headers, source codes and main). I put the three files in the same folder.